# "Колготки" (одежда) и "колготиться" - происхождение слов

Tags: этимология

Странное надо сказать слово *колготки*, ближайшее однокоренное (будто бы) слово *колготиться* - беспокоиться, суетиться, тревожиться и т.д.
А причем здесь женские *колготки*?

Comment: @Olsa ау, нужна ваша помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Насчет колготиться и колготок."колгота" - суета.
А давайте разберемся, откуда "суета" сначала, и как она связана по логике со штанами. ВЫ в штанину ногу суете  --"суете" !!!!Че потом, на одной ноге частенько пляшете, особенно, когда в спешке. Простенько и по логике. Когда суешь и не попасть-суета.
Теперь со штанами, а вообще зачем они-штаны?, да чтоб начало прятать, в первую очередь.
Синоним--кол.
А дальше слово хотел, чтоб видно не было. HOTEL--теперь гостиница, место , где прячутся переночевать. Г-H  готель, нормальный переход букв. Западенская мова.
То есть колготы--это штаны, а колготиться-это их суетливо одевать в спешке, понятное дело, почему.
Какое уж тут совпадение, чистая логика.
далее  в слове  punčochove, отчетливо видно слово--ховать. Осталось  punčo.
А из чего раньше штаны делали?  да из пеньки, как и вообще всю грубую одежду.
Это слово--пончо, искаженная пенька.Одежда, а не кусок ткани с дыркой,В чешском pončo. Явно не индейское. Это теперь пенька--конопля, от вроде как из латыни? В баскском языке  конопля--kalamuzko-кол мужицкий, где-то так..
Странновато?-нет. Там вообще навалом русских идиоматических выражений ныне непереводимых, как бы. В русском Конопля это конь и ОПЛЯ!.Зашел в заросли и беситься начал. Кана-бЕс--в латыни. Не смешно это, грустно, слишком перекликается с версией Фоменко.  Латынь - произведение католических монахов поздних средних веков, как и современная придуманная ими фантастическая история, от которой пляшут лингвисты.

Answer (score 1):

Колготки,как и кальсосоны и прочие "чулки" (в основе однокоренные слова), - слова нерусские, означают нечто, куда засовывают ноги.

Comment: Хмм.. я и так знаю, что это нечто куда засовывают ноги... но это какое имеет отношение к этимологии?

Comment: Если понятнее это "емкость, куда что-то можно поместить" в колготки - ноги,а в колчан - стрелы, а colchon (исп.) - это уже тюфяк или матрас. Общее, что есть у этих слов, это, что они обозначают нечто, в частности для этих слов "емкость", в которую что-то вкладывают.
Все зависит от того, что вы ищите, когда занимаетесь этимологией. Но даже по ближайшим этимологиям, которые путают с этимологией вообще, вы можете видеть более глубокий (т.е. исходный) смысл слова.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki, 

таким способом вы ничего не поймете. Сравните по буквам и по значению приведенные слова и сделайте непредвзятый вывод, а не отсылайте к давно устаревшим воззрениям об языковых семьях, каждая из которых произошла от своей группы обезьян.

Comment: @VVM, сравните по буквам своё мнение с обезьяньим - и вы поймете, что Вы недалеко от них ушли. Нет никой нужды пересматривать представления об этимологии в угоду "видящим" и ищущим, то, чего они не прятали.
С этим -  к Чудинову и прочим задорновым.

Comment: В чем причина такой агрессивности? Только в том, что у Вас нет имени? или в том, что Вы из общей серой массы ничего не видящих, а главное - не желающих слышать? 
Чулки, кальсоны, калготки, colchon, colchoneta (и матртас, и надувной матрасик для плаванья) - слова одного корня. Почитайте историю предмета (кальсон и колготок, может быть от Чехии  и Польши выйдите хотя бы к Франции). Если вы при этом не видите связи этих слов со словом колчан, это - проблемы не Чудинова, а Ваши собственные. 
Об этимологии не надо пересматривать представления, надо их иметь -etymon, надеюсь, придумали не Вы.

Comment: Всё проще, малоуважаемый поваелитель обезьян.  
Здесь люди общаются на серьезные темы и шарлатанство не приветствуется.  
А проблема у меня только одна. Нежелание общаться с апологетами чудиновщины и прочих новомодных лжеучений. Переходя на Ваш стиль: изучите хотя бы азы этимологии - потом будете рассуждать насчет "нежелающих слышать".

Comment: Настоящий доцент! Не стоит так колготиться! Лучше поищите родственные слова к слову колготки, не ограничиваясь польским и чешским, может быть, студентам будет, что сказать, или вы и там ничего не мечите, считая, что и это схавают?

Comment: Ну, собственно, я математик. У нас со смыслами строго: или доказано, или нет.

Comment: Мальчики и девочки, хватит перепалки! Не засоряйте сайт! Я открываю страницы сайта не для того, чтобы читать ваши подколки

Comment: Вот и не читайте. Дело не в подколках. Просто не хочется, чтобы вы и все остальные читали всякую ахинею.

Comment: @behemothus, если Вы не хотите, чтобы мы читали всякую ахинею, пожалуйста, удалите весь этот диалог-перепалку, у Вас ведь есть такая возможность! Я свое замечание удалю, оно и вправду грубое.

Comment: Только на условиях взаимеости. Не свами, разумеется, а с VVM. Потому как я реагировал на его посты. Даже не на личность. Если не бороться с ними, то онм нас сборят.

Comment: Зачем Вам взаимность? Удалите и свое, и его. На то Вам и права дадены!

Comment: Заново напишут! Согласна с Виктором, хочется читать содержательные ответы и комментарии. И получать удовольствие от общения с умным собеседником.

Answer (score 1):

Не вводите человека в заблуждение. Колчан — слово тюркское, никакого отношения к колготкам не имеет.
Колготки — слово чешского происхождения и, собственно, образовалось случайно. Когда наши туристы еще в советские времена увидели в магазинах невиданную одежду "калготы панчухове", они решили, что это название изделия. А на самом деле, по-чешски "калготы" — это просто штаны. А "калготки" — вообще женские трусики.

Comment: Тогда откуда слово *колготиться*?

Comment: Да уж точно не от колготок.)))

Answer (score 1):

Колготиться- от утаревшего (но сохранившегося как диалектное) существительного  "колгота" - суета.

Насчет колготок - не уверен на сто процентов, что это именно чешское, скорее уж польское, но сама по себе история весьма правдоподобна. Во всяком случае других разумных объяснений нет.

А нет... По-чешски действительно - kalhoty punčochove. Только читается это кАлхоты пУнчоховы. Дословный перевод - что-то вроде "трусы из чулочных изделеий". 
Все-таки надо польскую версию разобрать...

Нет, сдаюсь. На польском нет похожих слов. Остаётся предположить, что наши туристы только читали написанное, причем весьма далеко от чешкого произношения.

Comment: то есть это просто совпадение *колгота* и *колготы*. Оч. странно, не может быть такого, чтобы это простое совпадение. Учитывая даже чешско-польские корни, наверняка есть общий предок/корень - языки то славянские!

Comment: Можете назвать совпадением. Хотя это дело настолько обычное, что даже такого определение в общем-то не заслуживает. Просто похожие, созвучные слова, какии числа несть.  
Про польские я снимаю. Просто чешские. Да и не говорило бы это ни о чем. Масса примеров тому, что слова могут звучать похоже, не являясь родственными, и наоборот. Вы вот, например, знаете, что слова "начало" и "конец" родствены на праславянском уровне и означали раньше одно и тоже?

Comment: Ничего удивительного, что разные слова сближаются по произношению. Во-первых, буквосочетаний не так уж и много. Во-вторых, они обкатываются под привычки и строй речи каждого народа.  
Аналогичное явление есть и в биологии: животные, живущие в одинаковых условиях, становятся похожими и внешне. Вспомните, хотя бы плавники дельфинов! Что ж они, рыбы после этого?

Answer (score 1):

Откуда Вы взяли версию о польском происхождении слова колготы?? Слова колготы / калготы итп. в польском языке нет. Колготы по-польски называются rajstopy = райстопы!!!

Этимология слова колгота / колготня мне все-равно не понятна, никто толком не объяснил. Значение понятно, но откуда слово взялось?